# ERROR in node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/lib/jwtoptions.token.d.ts(2,50):

Tags: angular, authentication, jwt, node-modules

when compiling the angular project, I encounter an error like below.

I have tried to delete and recreate the node_modules file many times, but I did not get any results.

can you help me?

error message;

ERROR in node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/lib/jwtoptions.token.d.ts(2,50): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'unknown'.

[image: ERROR in node_modules/@auth0/angular-jwt/lib/jwtoptions.token.d.ts(2,50):]

The content of my company.service.ts file is below.

[image]

Comment: could you provide the source code of `company.service.ts` please, it seems there is a problem with imports

Comment: i shared as answer

Comment: Please [edit] your question and paste a [mre] of your code and error messages in the body of the question as text and not as pictures. No-one can attempt to rerun your code to reproduct your problem if it is a picture and no-one can search for it. If you're having difficulty formatting it the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) has full details.

Comment: i did a minimal reproducible example

Comment: I am not sure what version of Angular you are running but I had this issue and found it to be a version dependency problem. Check out my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63400257/error-in-node-modules-auth0-angular-jwt-lib-jwtoptions-token-d-ts2-50-error/63600679#63600679